# Moshi: how to fix "Inappropriate blocking method call" warning in the coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, moshi, android-jetpack-datastore

I use this with `DataStore` to convert Flow result and it show a warning for the Moshi `fromJson` method

```
dataStore.data.map {
    val json = it[key]
    json?.let { adapter.fromJson(json) } ?: defaultValue
}
```

Is it possible to fix this without resorting to ignoring the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to change the execution thread (change context of execution) for `fromJson` method using `withContext` method:

```
dataStore.data.map { data ->
    val json = data[key]
    json?.let { parseJson(it) } ?: defaultValue
}

suspend fun parseJson(json: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    adapter.fromJson(json)
}
```

Comment: It still shows this warning inside parseJson()